# Linked list removing from tail

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

I am trying to remove at the end from a singly Linked List.I don't have a tail variable which keeps reference to the last item on the list..Therefore this is my implementation.My question is **after while loop** if I set `current=null;` it doesn't work(It doesn't remove the last node).I have to set `current.next=null;`.
But what do I have to add **next** for `current.next=null;`.Even if I say current=null; doesn't that mean point the node current to null.Can someone please explain why I have to use next there?

```
public void removeFromTail() throws EmptyStackException{
        if(head==null){
            throw new EmptyStackException("can't delete .Empty list");}
        else if(head.next==null){
            head=null;
        }
        else{
            ListNode current=head;
            while(current.next.next!=null){
                current=current.next;
            }


        current.next=null;}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`current` is a reference to the current position in your linked list. After the while loop, `current` refers to the second to last item. When you say `current.next = null`, you make the current object's `next` become `null`. That makes the current object the last object.

When you say `current = null`, you are just setting your local reference variable to `null`. In other words, it no longer refers to your list. It refers to `null`.

Answer (score 1):

When you do `current=null;` you set the (local) variable `current` to `null`, but still the same object is pointed in your list, you want the object in the list which points to the last object with his `next` member (`someobject.next`) to stop pointing there, so you need to change the value of `someobject.next`, e.g. `someobject.next = null;`

Answer (score 0):

Why not use remove method of List interface?

```
LinkedList<String> sss = new LinkedList<String>();
sss.add("a");
sss.add("b");
sss.remove(sss.size() - 1); // removes "b"
```

Comment: I am writing this on my own just for practise